# reading a large (>50MB) pivot table from Excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, openpyxl, large-data

**Summary:** I am trying to load a large (>50MB) pivot table from Excel using Python.

**In detail:** I use openpyxl to load my workbook and would like to read the pivot table from it by executing the following lines of code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook  # Import openpyxl  [0]
wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsx') # Load workbook    [1]
ws = wb["myWorksheet"]              # Load worksheet   [2]
pivot = ws._pivots[0]               # Load pivot table [3]
```

**Result:** During command [1] I can observe slowly increasing RAM utilization until RAM is full and my system crashes. So [1] is not fully executed.

Second try was to use [1] with the `read_only=True` parameter. With this, I can load my workbook without problems, but command [3] fails:

```
AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute '_pivots'
```

Ok, understood. But how else can I read a >50MB pivot table from an Excel file with Python without requiring tens of gigabytes of RAM?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there is no alternative to having enough RAM. Is the Excel file 50 MB? I would reckon you need ≥ 2 GB to read this.

Comment: The Excel file is 64 MB and I have 8 GB RAM on Windows. When I run the code above, it takes about 20 minutes and Python keeps filling up the RAM and then the swap file until the system crashes at 100% RAM usage and nearly 30 GB swap file usage... So this operation takes significantly more RAM then I would expect.

Comment: You are limited by your hardware it sounds like. Make sure you have 64 bit Python installed to give you the best chance of utilising your machine but ultimately 8gb of RAM is nothing these days. Ideally you want 32gb.

Comment: Assume the OS and other stuff takes up at least half your RAM and that doesn't give you much. Try on another system with more RAM.